# connection timeout while calling another 3rd party rest api using rest temple in java aws lamba

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, resttemplate

I am trying to call 3rd party rest api using rest template in aws lambda but connection timeout is happening. this third party api is working fine in postman.
Below is the code snippet

```
@Override
public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent apply(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent request) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    EmailRequest emailRequest = gson.fromJson(request.getBody(),EmailRequest.class);
    System.out.println("Inside function");
    APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent responseEvent = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
    if(emailRequest!=null && emailRequest.getUserId() !=null && emailRequest.getPid()!=null) {
        Optional<UserDetail> userDetail = userRepository.findById(emailRequest.getUserId());
        Optional<Prospect> prospect = prospectRepository.findById(emailRequest.getPid());
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<Prospect> entity = new HttpEntity<>(prospect.get(), httpHeaders);
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(userDetail.get().getCrmUrl(), entity, String.class);
            if(result.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
                responseEvent.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
                responseEvent.withBody("Issue while sending email details");
            }
            responseEvent.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
            responseEvent.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT.value());
            responseEvent.withBody("Rest templete time out");
            return responseEvent;
        }

        responseEvent.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        responseEvent.withBody("UserId crm : " + userDetail.get().getCrmUrl() +" and Prospect first name : " + prospect.get().getFirstName());
    } else {
        responseEvent.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        responseEvent.withBody("Please check the request data");
    }
    return responseEvent;
}
```

Please help me out how can I access third party rest api in aws lambda.

Comment: Is your lambda in a vpc?

Comment: @Marcin I am using same VPC as per my RDS instance.

Comment: For now I have removed VPC from RDS instace.  But will try and explore it with VPC.

Comment: Yes, It was really helpful and It gave me idea to explore more on VPC. Thanks for the explaination.

Comment: To accept the answer you have to press a "tick" button under its upvote/downvote buttons.

Comment: I also noticed that most of your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances of your issues being actually answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to the fact that a lambda function in a VPC does not have access to the internet by default. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet):

> When you connect a function to a VPC in your account, the function **can't access the internet** unless your VPC provides access.

A popular way to overcome this is through **NAT gateway** and **private subnet** as described in:

- [How do I give internet access to a Lambda function that's connected to an Amazon VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Comment: Can I have a RDS postgres instance without vpc, and lambda without vpc??? Also will it solve this problem without creating NAT gateway?

Comment: @Rahul The only way not to use VPC, is to have your RDS publicly available, which is not a good security practice. Regarding NAT, no there is no other way to access internet, unless you want to proxy through other lambda function.